# Scala: assigning a variable once without val

Tags: scala

This is what I want to do -

```
class A(some args) {
  var v: SomeType = null
  def method1(args) = {
    v = something1
    ...
    method3
  }

  def method2(args) = {
    v = something2
    ...
    method3
  }
  def method3 = {
    // uses v
  }
}
```

In this specific case method1 and 2 are mutually exclusive and either one of them is called exactly once in the lifetime of an instance of A. Also, v is assigned once. I would prefer making it a val. But since I need method2 or method3's context to initialize v, I can't do that in the constructor.

How can achieve this "val" behavior? I can think of modifying method1 and method2 to apply methods, but I don't like the idea. Moreover, method1 and 2 have the same argument signature (hence apply would need some more info to distinguish the 2 types of calls).

Comment: Why can't the `v` value be passed as an argument to `m3`?  Is `m3` being invoked from outside of the `class`? If so, can `m3` be called before either `m1` or `m2`? (Which sounds like a design flaw.)

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need to enforce that `method1` or `method2` can only be called once, and that `method3` can only be called afterwards.

Comment: @jwvh m3 is a private method, should have mentioned that in my snippet.

Comment: @Jasper-M I am currently ensuring this ordering and exactly once by keeping a var and checking for null and throwing exception if it's not, kind of sjrd's solution. I was looking for a simpler/cleaner solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An important question is: what exactly do you call "val behavior"? To me "val behavior" is that is assigned once immediately when it is declared, which can be enforced statically. You seem to want to enforce that `v` is not assigned twice. You possibly also want to enforce it is never *read* before it is assigned. You could create a very small helper box for that:

```
final class OnceBox[A] {
  private[this] var value: Option[A] = None

  def update(v: A): Unit = {
    if (value.isDefined)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Value assigned twice")
    value = Some(v)
  }

  def apply(): A = {
    value.getOrElse {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Value not yet assigned")
    }
  }
}
```

and now your snippet:

```
class A(some args) {
  val v = new OnceBox[SomeType]
  def method1(args) = {
    v() = something1
    ...
    method3
  }

  def method2(args) = {
    v() = something2
    ...
    method3
  }
  def method3 = {
    // uses v
    v()
  }
}
```

Oh and, just kidding, but [Ozma](https://github.com/sjrd/ozma) has single-assignment vals built-in :-p

Answer (score 6):

Similar idea to the other answer, but instead of subtypes, a field.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A {
  private[this] var context: Int = _
  lazy val v: String =
    context match {
      case 1 => "one"
      case 2 => "two"
      case _ => ???
    }
  def m1() = { context = 1 ; v }
  def m2() = { context = 2 ; v }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@62ce72ff

scala> a.m2
res0: String = two

scala> a.m1
res1: String = two
```

Comment: `v` throws until context is set, then works as normal.

Comment: I considered this idea earlier. But the problem with my specific use-case is, it's a complex initialization (many variables calculated in m1 and m2). So context has to be a set of values (may be a class with the needed fields). Of course I can extend this approach and say - v and context are of the same type and when assigned results to the same object as well. But that's way too complex to enforce on future devs that they use v instead of context.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
   class A private (mtdType: Int, ...) {
      val v = mdtType match {
        case 1 => method1(...)
        case 2 => method2(...)
      }
   }


   object A {
     def withMethod1(...) = new A(1, ...)
     def withMethod2(...) = new A(2, ...)
   }
```

Or, another possibilty:

```
   sealed trait A {
     val v
     def method3 = println(v)
   }

   class Method1(...) extends A {
      val v = method1(...)
   }

   class Method2(...) extends A {
      val v = method2(...)
   }
```